# puzzled by "Already defines a member with the same parameter types" error

Tags: c#, covariance, contravariance, invariance

Not understanding why these to `Map` methods have the same parameter types, since they don't appear too.  Is this a covariance thing or just a generic signature thing?

I would like to understand it in general to avoid writing code that will have this problem. (And explain the catch-22 of how it is both the same and not-the-same)

```cs
class A { }
class B
{
    void Map<T>(T obj) where T : A { }
    void Map<T>(T obj) where T : B { } // SAME -- "Map" already defined, can't compile

    void Test(A a, B b)
    {
        Map(a);
        Map(b); // NOT SAME -- if the B-mapper is removed then this won't compile
    }
}
```

This change will "fix" it: `void Map<T>(in T obj)` ??

This seems even more "Not the Same":

```
Ta Map<Tb, Ta>(Tb obj) where Ta: A, new() where Tb : B, new() { return new Ta(); }
Tb Map<Ta, Tb>(Ta obj) where Ta: A, new() where Tb : B, new() { return new Tb(); } // ERROR
```

E.g., want to Map<Tsrc, Tdest> from Tsrc to Tdest, by convention, but can't.
Need swap generic order:

```
Ta Map<Ta, Tb>(Tb obj) where Ta: A, new() where Tb : B, new() { return new Ta(); }
Tb Map<Ta, Tb>(Ta obj) where Ta: A, new() where Tb : B, new() { return new Tb(); } // OK NOW
```

Note: in these last two cases the parameter types are **not** changed, even though one is legal and the other isn't.
The `in` invariance modifier would also fix this, which I believe is a clue to understanding what is going on.

Comment: Just a generic signature thing. Consider `MapA<T>(T) where T : A` and `MapB<T>(T) where T : B` naming instead, perhaps

Comment: It seems related to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2013). Long story short, generic constraints are not part of the method signature.

Comment: A type can be classified under numerous different constraints, so while modifying the constraint can change the subset of possible types, it doesn't guarantee that that subset doesn't intersect with another constraint's subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```cs
void Map<T>(T obj) where T : struct { }
void Map<T>(T obj) where T : unmanaged { }

Map<int> map = new Map<int>(1);
```

Which version does our map instance use? [Both are just as applicable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) for an `int`. And as the actual signatures are identical, they now become ambiguous.

Signatures are based on the number of arguments, the order of the arguments, and the argument types.

[Generic type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) are not considered part of a signature. They are used as "rules" to be followed when generating the actual classes/methods/delegates etc for use at runtime. Once the compiler generates each different version of your generic code necessary for the runtime, the constraints are no longer needed.

`void Map<T>(in T obj)` is indeed a different signature than `void Map<T>(T obj)` because `in T` is not the same as `T` (or `out T`, `ref T`, et al).

`void Map<T>(T obj) where T : A` has an identical signature to `void Map<T>(T obj) where T : B` since the constraint is all that changed. **The number of arguments, the order of the arguments, and the argument types** are all the same.

Comment: Signatures are not based on return types for purposes of overload resolution.  Also, the last example didn't flip the generics order, specifically (that would do nothing, and is exactly the snippet #2 in OP's post) - it's the fact that the parameter is now of a different type that allows the overload resolution to find the best fitting method.

Comment: You are 100% correct about return types, my brain must have taken a timeout on me mid sentence lol. Edited accordingly.

Comment: OK, so forget about constraints and just think of it a T1, T2,  .. and then it all makes sense, i.e. if they both are Map(T1 obj) no matter what T1 is, that is as hard as c# will try to distinguish them (except for 'in' and out/ref)